# Navigation bar with button that controls whether it's hidden or displayed

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Was wondering if someone could redirect me to a site/tutorial with a horizontal navigation bar at the top of the page, with a button that hides/displays it. I think it was like a semicircle that was attached to the bottom of the bar, with a down/up arrow according to whether the bar was hidden or displayed.

I've been looking on the internet, and cannot find a site that has this, or a tutorial that teaches you how to implement this onto your site.

I could've sworn I've seen it before, just not sure where.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any good tutorials to do this, so I have written a small snippet for you using just HTML & CSS (no JS). I've used a checkbox to toggle the navigation bar. The navigation `.bar` is toggled using the `:checked` pseudo element and the `+` selector. There are some comments in the CSS, I'm not sure if everything is clear, so please comment, if there is anything unclear.

```css
/* General styling */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  /* smooth animation (transition) */
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
.bar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
.bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
/* The toggle is positioned absolute to be after the bar */

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  /* the animation */
  transition: top 0.4s;
  /* doesn't look like a checkbox */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* styling */
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  /* position */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  /* misc */
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
/* set the arrow with the :after pseudo element */

.toggle:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* you could use any other icon here */
  content: "▼";
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  top: 2px;
  color: #666;
}
/* change the content when checked */

.toggle:checked:after {
  content: "▲";
}
/* the magic part */

/* move the toggle down when toggled */

.toggle:checked {
  top: 80px;
}
.toggle:not(:checked) {
  top: 0px;
}
/* get the next element with the + selector (the .bar) and move it down */

.toggle:checked + .bar {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.toggle:not(:checked) + .bar {
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">

  <!-- the toggle -->
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />

  <!-- the navigation bar -->
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Page #1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page #2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page #3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page #4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Q: If I wanted to use two custom images instead of the tickboxes, where would I insert the <img> tags? Is it the "content" key on the .toggle:after and .toggle:checked:after bits?

Comment: And, sorry, how would I set it up so when I hover over the button, it changes to another image (which is the same size and shape, just a different color)?

Comment: You would have to set the image as background image for the `.toggle` element, because it is not possible to use any HTML in `<input>` Tags. To change the background image on hover just use the `.toggle:hover` pseudo class and change the background image. If you want to remove the icon just remove the `.toggle:after` and `.toggle:checked:after`.

Answer (score 0):

I effectively and functionally accomplished changing the display of an image. You can check the hover effect on the photo imgs on my legitimately/[safely - no redirection, ads, or popups] hosted web page:
http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Photos%20-%20GladHeart.html

css style code snippet for row-2 is:

```
div#divContainer-photoRow-2 { position:relative; left:calc(50% - 140px) ; 
    width:280px; height:210px ; 
        padding: 40px 0 40px 0 ; 
  }

#div-photoRow-2 { position:absolute ; 
    width:280px; height:210px ; 
  } 
#photoRow-2_1st-photo { position:relative ; 
  } 
#imgswap-photoRow-2_1st-photo { background-image:url("./Photos%20-%20GladHeart_files/AlaskaRun-ArchesNP-2013.jpg"); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block; width:280px; height:210px; 
  } 
#imgswap-photoRow-2_1st-photo:hover img { visibility:hidden ; }
```

html body code snippet for row-2 is:

```
<div id="divContainer-photoRow-2">

<div id="div-photoRow-2_1st-photo">
<span id="imgswap-photoRow-2_1st-photo" class="photoHoverOutlineColor">
  <span id="photoRow-2_1st-photo">
    <img src="./Photos%20-%20GladHeart_files/tn_Antelope_Island.jpg" 
    alt="Antelope Island" width="280" height="210"/>
</span></span>
</div>

</div>
```